# Mensaje de Alerta con Fechas de Vencimiento en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

hola alguien que me ayude en la lógica de este sistema de alertas tengo una tabla con la fecha_inicio que es cuando se comienza el mantenimiento y una fecha_final cuando debe de terminar, lo que quiero es que dos días antes de que termine ese rango de fechas me indique que esta por vencer el mantenimiento y cuando llegue la fecha de vencimiento que me diga que ya se venció por ejemplo:

si el mantenimiento inicio el 2019-06-12 debe mandarme una alerta o mensaje de que esta por vencer llegando a la fecha 2019-06-17 y cuando ya llegue al 2019-06-19 esa alerta o mensaje cambie a que el mantenimiento venció.
el mensaje o alerta lo quiero mostrar en una tabla en los `<td>` por ejemplo:"esta a 2 días de vencer"

esta es mi tabla después de la fecha_final va ir otro campo que diga vencimiento y ahí ir poniendo mis mensajes de alerta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí genero mi tabla:

```
 <div class="dataWrapper">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered table-condensed" id="exportar">

    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="">Fecha Inicio del Mtto</label>  
    <input id="min" name="min" type="text" placeholder="Fecha iniciar busqueda" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3"> 
    <label for="">Fecha Inicio del Mtto(cerrar rango)</label>  
    <input id="max" name="max" type="text" placeholder="Fecha cerrar busqueda" class="form-control">
    </div> 
    </div>

    <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
    <tr>  
    <th>ID_mtto</th>
    <th>Vehículo</th>
    <th>Servicio</th>
    <th>Tipo_Mtto</th>
    <th>Observaciones</th>
    <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
    <th>Fecha Final</th>
    <th>Vencimiento</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());
    $query="SELECT id_mtto,vehiculo,servicio,tipo_mtto,observaciones,fecha_inicio,fecha_final FROM mantenimiento ORDER BY id_mtto DESC";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

    $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));//nueva variable para vencimiento//

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { 
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td class='text-center'>".$row['id_mtto']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='text-center'>".$row['vehiculo']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['servicio']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='text-center'>".$row['tipo_mtto']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['observaciones']."</td>";

      echo "<td class='text-center'>".$row['fecha_inicio']."</td>";  
      echo "<td class='text-center'>".$row['fecha_final']."</td>";

        $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['fecha_final']);
        $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');

        // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
        if ($dias <= 0) {
        echo '<td>Mantenimiento vencido</td>';
        } 
        elseif ($dias <= 2) {
        echo '<td>Está a ' . $dias . ' días de vencer</td>';
        }

      echo "</tr>";
       }
    mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Problemas al llamar tabla".mysqli_error());
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

código para generar data-table y ocultar tabla:

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#exportar').DataTable();
} );

$( ()=> {
  $('#exportar').DataTable();
  $(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){

  if( !$('.dataWrapper').is(':visible') ) {
    $('.dataWrapper').show();
  } else {
    $('.dataWrapper').hide();
  }
  });
});
```

código para generar búsqueda por rango de fechas:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var table = $('#exportar').DataTable();
    $('#min,#max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    });
});

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

        var dateIni = $('#min').val();
        var dateFin = $('#max').val();

        var indexCol = 5;

        dateIni = dateIni.replace(/-/g, "");
        dateFin= dateFin.replace(/-/g, "");

        var datofini = aData[indexCol].replace(/-/g, "");

        if (dateIni === "" && dateFin === "")
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(dateIni === "")
        {
            return datofini <= dateFin;
        }

        if(dateFin === "")
        {
            return datofini >= dateIni;
        }

        return datofini >= dateIni && datofini <= dateFin;
    }
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este con el DateTime::diff si se puede pero es necesario que vayas dándole click ha cada registro para que haga el calculo, como se podría automatizar eso que no fuera necesario ir dando click a cada función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) para calcular la diferencia en días ([o lo que quieras](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php)) entre 2 fechas. Una vez que obtenés ese dato podes armar la lógica como prefieras.

Todas las fechas se están calculando como si fueran las "00:00 hs".

Ejemplo:

```
$fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo "<td class='text-center'>".$row['fecha_inicio']."</td>";  
    echo "<td class='text-center'>".$row['fecha_final']."</td>";

    $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['fecha_final']);
    $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');

    // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
    if ($dias <= 0) {
        echo '<td>Mantenimiento vencido</td>';
    } elseif ($dias <= 2) {
        echo '<td>Está a ' . $dias . ' días de vencer</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td></td>';
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: puedes ver otra vez ya edite con tu código mi tabla  quedo como lo muestro arriba pero tenia propiedades datatable que al poner tu código se quitaron tenia un search y un paginado es por mal cerrado de llaves ?

Comment: @jasieltorres copiá el nuevo código que puse que el anterior tenía un error en la comparación con la fecha actual. A tu código le está faltando definir un `<th>` extra debajo de `<th>Fecha Final</th>`. Debe ser ese el problema.

Comment: ya copie tu nuevo código y ya puse el th pero aun sigue sin salir las propiedades datatable no aparece el search ni paginado

Comment: $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['fecha_final']);
    $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');

    // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
    if ($dias <= 0) {
        echo '<td>Mantenimiento vencido</td>';
    } elseif ($dias <= 2) {
        echo '<td>Está a ' . $dias . ' días de vencer</td>';
    }

Comment: al agregar eso y el th extra se me quitan las propiedades , si quito el codigo y el th vuelven aparecer

Comment: @jasieltorres no se como estás usado datatable, publicá el código HTML generado o algo con lo que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=exportar - Requested unknown parameter '7' for row 2, column 7. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: se genera el error de arriba no es por que en el campo de vencimiento esta esperando parámetros pero algunos campos aun no cumplen las condiciones y no se llenan por lo tanto quedan vacíos y el datatables no los lee

Comment: Editá tu pregunta y agregá el código de datatable. Sino imposible saber a que se refiere.

Comment: ya edite y puse el error , uso data-table de manera simple solo para poner un buscador y paginado luego un código para buscar por rango de fechas y es todo funciona bien al quitar el código que me proporcionaste pero al ponerlo ya no funciona, puse una imagen de como se ve la tabla no realiza búsquedas y faltan propiedades

Comment: creo ya solucione el problema muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvió de mucho no sabia por donde empezar con eso de las fechas

Comment: Excelente, cuál era el problema? Ahora que veo la imagen, lo que está faltando es imprimir un `<td></td>` vacío si no se da ninguno de los 2 casos. Pondría un `else` después del `elseif` y ahí lo agregaría.